# getting error ReconcileDynamicAxis

Tags: cntk

I am using WeightedLogistic in BS or weighted_binary_cross_entropy in python.
After defining weights as simple array of two floats I am getting  following error.

FrameRange's dynamic axis is inconsistent with matrix. They are compatible though--are you missing a ReconcileDynamicAxis operation?

Comment: Would you mind posting the network description, and the definition of your input_variables?

Comment: Does this post help you: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/462